# Issue with computed state and mutated state with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm seeing an issue with binded components set from Vuex state management.

I have a state store as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    id: 0,
    contentBlocks: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      contentBlock.id = state.id
      state.contentBlocks.push(contentBlock)
      state.id += 1
    },
    updateContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)
      Vue.set(state.contentBlocks, index, contentBlock)
    },
    removeContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)
      Vue.delete(state.contentBlocks, index)
    }
  }
})
```

I then loop over `state.contentBlocks` in my `baseComponent.vue` as follows:

```
<v-container pa-0 v-for="(contentBlock, index) in contentBlocks" v-bind:key="contentBlock.index">
  <component v-bind:is="contentBlock.blockComponent" v-bind:contentBlock="contentBlock"></component>
</v-container>
```

I then mutate `state.contentBlocks` by adding, updating and deleting content blocks. (I add blocks from the base component, deleting and updating from the child component that is bound to `<component></component>`.

I `get` the mutated `state.contentBlocks` to `BaseComponent.vue` using within `BaseComponent.vue`:

```
computed: {
    contentBlocks: () => store.state.contentBlocks,
}
```

When updating I see the following in console:

[image]

All is looking good. I then go to delete the block at index 1, which "works" on the state level:

[image]

But the DOM is not playing ball:

[image]

(!!) In the above, the indices of 0 and 2 are correct as the need to be, but the content in index 2 is that of the deleted index 1 (!!?) Help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `baseComponent.vue`, use a computed property to loop over the content blocks rather than the state of the vuex store:

```
<v-container pa-0 v-for="(contentBlock, index) in blocks" v-bind:key="contentBlock.index">
  <component v-bind:is="contentBlock.blockComponent" v-bind:contentBlock="contentBlock"></component>
</v-container>

computed: {
  blocks () {
    return this.$store.getters['contentBlocks']
  }
}
```

You'll need to add the corresponding getter to the store as well:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    id: 0,
    contentBlocks: []
  },
  getters: {
    contentBlocks: (state) => state.contentBlocks 
  }
  mutations: {
    addContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      contentBlock.id = state.id
      state.contentBlocks.push(contentBlock)
      state.id += 1
    },
    updateContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)
      Vue.set(state.contentBlocks, index, contentBlock)
    },
    removeContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)
      Vue.delete(state.contentBlocks, index)
    }
  }
})
```

Unrelated, but you can simply the `removeContentBlock` mutation to:

```
state.contentBlocks = state.contentBlocks.filter({id} => id !== contentBlock.id)
```

**update**

Add a key on the `component` elements:

```
<v-container pa-0 v-for="(contentBlock, index) in blocks" v-bind:key="contentBlock.index">
  <component v-bind:is="contentBlock.blockComponent" v-bind:contentBlock="contentBlock" :key="contentBlock.id"></component>
</v-container>
```

Comment: Don't know who is down voting this (I'll upvote for the gratitude of helping out and it seems a bit harsh). I appreciate the effort on this, hoped that it would work but unfortunately the same behaviour occurs...on deletion the DOM is keeping the old content but deleting the correct key...

Comment: I've done the same, reported both of them and flagged a weird comment on a previous question. Back to the issue tho - it seems like a fundamental issue with updating the DOM? On deleting, the updated value field (labelled `data-v-770f4dcd`) stays and the other one leaves? Really scratching my head at this...

Comment: I believe it's because of the dynamic components and how Vue will attempt to reuse a component. Adding a key attribute should solve it. Answer has been updated as well.

Comment: Boom! Your update worked perfectly. And my code is now working perfectively! Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers!

Comment: Just bumped up some of your accepted answers as well to mitigate the two clowns.